# Pending Contract issue in my iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-store

i have one free application on app store, two months before my developer account was expired and recently i have renewed my account.But in iTunes account i am getting pending contract request.Can any one suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Regards
Bodul Babu Shaik

Answer (score 1):

Login on [iTunes connect website](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/), then go to `Agreements, Tax, and Banking`. There, you could see your contracts and be able to  sign it.